# Is it bad practice to instantiate variables inside of $(document).ready as opposed to globally declaring them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I'm trying to avoid the use of global variables in my code, so I'm trying to use a work around by declaring them inside of `$(document).ready` and passing them as parameters to functions outside of `$(document).ready`, updating them, and then returning the updated value from those functions to manipulate the variables inside of `$(document).ready`.

Another way around this is to use `hidden` input fields to store variables but I also heard that was bad practice.

I'm wondering if I should just use global variables, do it the way I'm currently doing it, or use hidden input fields?

Below is a brief example of what I'm trying to accomplish. The variable validations is the variable I want to be able to use and update.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var validations = [];
    $('#inp').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            scanValidation(validations, function(valid){
                validations = valid;
            });
        }
    });
}):

function scanValidation(valid, cb){
    var scanval = $('#inp').val();
    if(valid.includes(scanval)){
        //display error
    }
    else{
        var validarr = valid.slice();
        validarr.push(scanval);
        var myData=JSON.stringify({ "name":"user1", "validations":validarr});
        //Makes an ajax call to see if the sent array validarr is a valid request
        apiCall(myData,'scanValidation',function(decoded) {
            if (decoded.Status!="ERROR") {
                valid = validarr;
            }
            else {
                //display error
            }
            return(cb(valid));

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Use correctly scoped variables.  Where the scope is will depend on the requirement.  You might like to look into javascript namespaces as it sounds like you have a lot of (read: too much) code in your document ready.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you are doing with the passing to functions outside the closure?  It sounds like you are going about it the right way trying to scope variables down, but just to make sure.

Comment: Side note, hidden variables are not the only way to store data in the DOM.  You can also use data-* fields to store related information for a logical entity on in the DOM as well.  Using jquery's data() to store the information this way will allow it to be accessed from any method that can get access to that element, and as it is associated with the element it is not truely global.

Comment: if everything is in one file can wrap it all in an IIFE and none of the variables will be global but will be available anywhere in that IIFE if declared in top scope. Declaring one global object and assigning properties instead of individual variables is another option

Answer (score 0):

Any variables declared within the immediately executed function below will NOT be in the global scope.

```
(function () {

  var someVar = 'someValue';

  $(document).ready(function() {

  });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it bad practice to instantiate variables inside of `$(document).ready` as opposed to globally declaring them?

No, not at all! Variables should always be declared in the scope they're needed in, nowhere else.

> Another way around this is to use hidden input fields to store variables but I also heard that was bad practice.

I've never heard of that, but yes it definitely sounds like a bad practise. That's just the same as a global variable, but a global variable stored in the DOM for some odd reason.

> I'm trying to avoid the use of global variables in my code, so I'm trying to use a work around by declaring them inside of `$(document).ready` and passing them as parameters to functions outside of `$(document).ready`, updating them, and then returning the updated value from those functions to manipulate the variables inside of `$(document).ready`.

That, admittedly, is a bit weird.

The easiest way to improve this is to move the function declaration inside the `ready` handler as well, and just access the variable there directly - with the additional bonus of not having a `scanValidation` global variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validations = [];
    function scanValidation() {
        var scanval = $('#inp').val();
        if (validations.includes(scanval)) {
            //display error
        } else {
            var validarr = validations.slice();
            validarr.push(scanval);
            var myData = JSON.stringify({"name": "user1", "validations": validarr});
            // Makes an ajax call to see if the sent array validarr is a valid request
            apiCall(myData, 'scanValidation', function(decoded) {
                if (decoded.Status!="ERROR") {
                    validations = validarr;
                } else {
                    //display error
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $('#inp').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            scanValidation();
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to make `scanValidation` reusable, so that it could be called from other places as well with its own array, I would suggest to create a factory function that creates validators, each of which is a closure over its own array. That way, the array is declared where it belongs, so that the user of the function does not have to store the state for them:

```
function makeScanValidator(display) { // any other configuration
    var validations = [];
    // returns closure
    return function scanValidation(scanval) { // take it as an argument
        if (validations.includes(scanval)) {
            display(/* error */);
        } else {
            var validarr = validations.concat([scanval]);
            var myData = JSON.stringify({"name": "user1", "validations": validarr});
            apiCall(myData, 'scanValidation', function(decoded) {
                if (decoded.Status!="ERROR") {
                    validations = validarr;
                } else {
                    display(/* error */);
                }
            });
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    var validate = makeScanValidator(function display() { … });
    $('#inp').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            validate(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```